# Java get spicific value from String

Tags: javascript, android, string

I have string

```
String path =   test1$milestones1$XYZf@image2@@image3@
```

I want to only strings test1 and XYZ. How can I get that substring.
I am using substring through index. 
Thanks,

Comment: Java is not Javascript,  they're a completely different languages,

Answer (score -1):

You should use regular expressions for that. Regular expression is a powerful tool to search patterns within a string extract or replace the parts you are interested in.

For example, if you want to replace all the digits contained within a sentence, you can do something like:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("This my card number: 4565 4593 2575 5144");
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("*"));
```

It will print

```
This my card number: **** **** **** ****
```

Here is a [good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) where you can learn how to use it.

Comment: can you explain this??

Comment: Please read the tutorial I gave you previously, there is all information you need, especially within the "Overview" section